# How to use paperscript from external source?

Tags: javascript, paperjs

I'm trying to learn  paper.js from  tutorials, but i'cant make it work from external file  .What is the easiest way to implement external paperscript files?

Answer (score 5):

Like stated in the [Getting started](http://paperjs.org/tutorials/getting-started/working-with-paper-js/) tutorial, if you want to use Paperjs with an external file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/paper.js"></script>
    <script type="text/paperscript" src="js/myScript.js" canvas="myCanvas"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" resize></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Be sure to specify:

- the script type "text/**paperscript**"
- your canvas ID with the attribute "canvas"

Comment: I am having the same problem. I have copied and pasted directly from the getting started tutorial which matches your answer but it doesn't work for me. Only when the code is inside my .htm file.

Comment: If you are using 0.9.11, some days ago I spotted that there was a bug with this specific version. So try with 0.9.10 it suppose to work. https://github.com/paperjs/paper.js/issues/332

Comment: @FR6 thanks, rolling back to v0.9.10 from v0.9.12 fixed my problem where multiple canvas objects referencing a single external script only worked for the last canvas.

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem as yours.
I use the 0.12.15 version and I finaly get what was the problem.

For me, it was the synthax of the script. I use const, let and arrow function but the paperscript parser is not able to understand these kind of writing.

Failing code :

```
const rectangles = [
  new paper.Rectangle(new paper.Point(10, 10), new paper.Size(100, 50)),
  new paper.Rectangle(new paper.Point(10, 150), new paper.Size(100, 50)),
  new paper.Rectangle(new paper.Point(10, 300), new paper.Size(100, 50)),
  new paper.Rectangle(new paper.Point(10, 450), new paper.Size(100, 50))
]

rectangles.forEach((rectangle) => {
  const path = new paper.Path.Rectangle(rectangle)
  path.fillColor = "#e9e9ff"
})
```

Working code :

```
var rectangles = [
  new paper.Rectangle(new paper.Point(10, 10), new paper.Size(100, 50)),
  new paper.Rectangle(new paper.Point(10, 150), new paper.Size(100, 50)),
  new paper.Rectangle(new paper.Point(10, 300), new paper.Size(100, 50)),
  new paper.Rectangle(new paper.Point(10, 450), new paper.Size(100, 50))
]

rectangles.forEach(function(rectangle){
  var path = new paper.Path.Rectangle(rectangle)
  path.fillColor = "#e9e9ff"
  path.on
})
```

Comment: Can someone explain why var is good and const is bad?

Answer (score 0):

--What about the new versions now? I still have the issue and Paperjs is at version 0.11.5?--

Actually I found the solution via another student in Udemy -Git link [here](https://github.com/banketasii/PatatapClone). Go to the paper-full.js (it works only with the downloaded version, not CDN) and transform the line

```
    xhr.open((options.method || 'get').toUpperCase(), options.url,
    Base.pick(options.async, true));
```

into only

```
xhr.open((options.method || 'get').toUpperCase(), options.url);
```

I understood that's not to be used in normal website as it's against a security protocols, so it's just for practicing. The async method is optional according to Paperjs.
By the way, for me it works on Firefox, but not in Chrome.