# External script not working in PaperJS v0.9.22

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, paperjs

I am new to paperJS and I'm trying to include an external paperscript file in html, but it isn't working. While the inline scripting is working fine. My code are:

HTML Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/paper.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/paperscript" src = "js/myScript.js" canvas = "myCanvas" >
    </script>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" resize></canvas>
```

paperScript Code (myScript.js):

```
// Create a Paper.js Path to draw a line into it:
var path = new Path();
// Give the stroke a color
path.strokeColor = 'black';
var start = new Point(100, 100);
// Move to start and draw a line from there
path.moveTo(start);
// Note the plus operator on Point objects.
// PaperScript does that for us, and much more!
path.lineTo(start + [ 100, -50 ]);
```

I found an old link on stackOverflow which says that using version 0.9.10 fix the problem. But is that issue still not fixed in newer version?
Here's the link:

[How to use paperscript from external source?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19726895/how-to-use-paperscript-from-external-source)

Comment: What do you mean by "isn't working"? Does it throw an exception? Just not draw?

Comment: @bmacnaughton: it doesn't throw any exception.. It just not draw..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not paperJs issue. Here I was trying to load a resource from the local file system, which chrome doesn't permit (Violation of its same-origin policy) and so we need a local web server.[Why?](http://levelzero.quora.com/Why-Local-Web-Server)

Local web server can be setup using WAMP (on Windows), MAMP (on OS X), LAMP(for ubuntu). It can aslo be setup by Python http-server and NodeJS http-server.

Answer (score 0):

The only guess I can make based on the information here is that you're loading `paper-core.js`, not `paper-full.js`. paperscript is not implemented in `paper-core.js`.

The behavior if it's `paper-core.js` would be that your code is never called because there is nothing to interpret paperscript.

Comment: I have used paper-full.js also but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Have you set a breakpoint or logged in your code to see if it is being executed?

Comment: I changed paper script file from paper.js to paper-full.js

Answer (score 0):

Actually I found the solution via another student in Udemy -Git link [here](https://github.com/banketasii/PatatapClone). Go to the paper-full.js (it works only with the downloaded version, not CDN) and transform the line

```
xhr.open((options.method || 'get').toUpperCase(), options.url,
Base.pick(options.async, true));
```

into only

```
xhr.open((options.method || 'get').toUpperCase(), options.url);
```

I understood that's not to be used in normal website as it's against a security protocols, so it's just for practicing. The async method is optional according to Paperjs. By the way, for me it works on Firefox, but not in Chrome.